# Active reports subreport multiple pge issue

Tags: activereports

I am using Active reports to generate a report.
The maiin report has 4 grids. For first 3 grids I am using sub reports and for the last grid , the main report is used.
Now the problem is if the records in sub report is spanning across multiple pages, the whole report is being displayed multiple times. However if the sub report has , say some, 20 records, the report displays each section just once. 
FYI, in the details section I have an image which is supposed to be displayed only once when the report is run, followed by 3 grids ( 3 sub reports) and a grid(not a sub report).
In the report start event, am initialising the subreports like

subreport1 = new SubReport1();

In the report end event am disposing it like

subreport1 = null

and in the details_Format event of the main report, am 
DetailedReport.Report = subreport1 ;

Please help me in resolving this issue at the earliest.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out??

Answer (score 0):

What other code do you have in the reports' events? This is almost certainly caused by changing some setting or changing the data/query in the subreports from an inappropriate event. All settings or changes made to the subreport should be done in the `Format` event of the section containing the subreport control.

Also, although not a problem in Detail_Format (assuming all your subreport controls are in the Detail section) you should be able to do the `DetailedReport.Report = subreport1` and similar statements only once in the main report's `ReportStart` event. Probably no noticeable effect, but it should simplify the code slightly and remove the redundant `SubreportControl.Report.set` calls.